# Converting images in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am facing a few problems here.  I have a socket server and my app uploads images to it.  Now if I say I have 1 million customers each one 1mb for image, I should leave 1 terabyte for just profile images, which is too much.  I am seeking a way to convert all image files to max 100 kb size, is such thing possible?  If so what should I search for?

And also I'm selecting image files from disk, like this:

```
  File file = new File("storage/sdcard/LifeMatePrivate/ProfileImage  
  /ProfileImage,imagechange_1,"+imagenamer+".jpg")
```

But as you see it just selects images with prefix.jpg.  Is there a way I can the file with any extension? Thanks.

```
  public void SaveImage(View v){
    System.out.println(path);
    String Path = path;
    //File file=new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza2.jpg");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("storage/sdcard/Pictures
 /reza2.jpg");  

    // you can change the format of you image compressed for what do you 
 want;  
    //now it is set up to 640 x 960;  

    Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 960, true);  
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

    // CompressFormat set up to JPG, you can change to PNG or whatever you  
 want;  

    bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos); 


    //  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
//  returnIntent.putExtra("result",Path);
//  setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
//  Log.i("Image",path);
    finish();

}
```

this code is inside an activity stared with StartActivityForResult

Comment: in other way how can i convert a 1600x1200 image to a 635x479 ?

Comment: you can use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`method

Comment: `bmpCompressed` is new file in compressed format..now you have to pass it when you upload your file..

Comment: am sorry what do you mean pass it?

Comment: pass it to a new adress with outputstream?

Comment: it will create new `Bitmap` file.. so you have to change your old value to new

Comment: i didnt get it, but thanks for your effort, may be im alittle newbie, i accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to compress your images..

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefilepath);  

// you can change the format of you image compressed for what do you want;  
//now it is set up to 640 x 960;  

Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 960, true);  
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

// CompressFormat set up to JPG, you can change to PNG or whatever you want;  

bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
```

now `bmpCompressed` is a compressed file format

Comment: for some reasons, this is not changing its size even a bit, the new file adress is the same right?

Comment: its a working code...i have used it in my project.. you have to pass `imagepath` in `decodeFile()` and then it will create bitmap from it..then it will convert to small size which i defined (640x960) and then it is compressed...after that you have to use `bmpCompressed` for passing `Bitmap`

Comment: well im still trying to find the problem, cause i see the working due to increased heap, but either it changes the file adress, or there is a problem

Comment: can i give it another adress for outputstream?

Comment: u mentioned i have to pass bmpCompressed, well what did you mean? i should use outputstream for bmpCompressed?

Comment: it will create new Bitmap file (bmpCompressed).. so you have to change your old value to new one..

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to scale a bitmap :

**With given size :**

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

**Sampling image** using :

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options)
```